# What does "as in" mean? and how do you use this?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

I don't understand what 'as in' means or how to use it. For example"

> "savory  as in"Which do you prefer, sweet foods or savory foods?"

In this context, what does  "as in " mean  and where does it modify savory foods?

Comment: It simply means that the following phrase is an example of how the word is being used.

Comment: @Mitch OK. Might be a candidate to go elsewhere, though.

Comment: @AndrewLeach as in ELL?

Comment: @Mitch I can't see how *as* and *in* have anything but their normal meanings.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, I agree it is not idiomatic. But it does feel opaque somehow. If someone is asking, then it's not obvious. To say it is GenRef is an answer of sorts.

Answer (score 3):

'As in' doesn't modify anything; it is an idiom combining two prepositions: 'as' which makes a comparison, and 'in' which identifies a subset.  The quoted question after 'as in' serves as a noun phrase (because it is in quotes), and it contains the words being compared.

'As' can also be used as a conjunction [of comparison], but then neither the quotes or the combination with 'in' would be appropriate.